# Spring Security switch case in JSTL Tags

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security, taglib

Is there a way to convert a jsp code of the form

```xml
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">You're an user</security:authorize>
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">You're an admin</security:authorize>
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_SADMIN')">You're a superadmin</security:authorize>
```

to another form, similar to the following (doesn't work)?

```xml
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
    You're an user
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    You're an admin
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="hasRole('ROLE_SADMIN')">
    You're a superadmin
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    You have no relevant role
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

More precisely, is there a way to substitute this Spring Security taglib functionality with JSTL tags?

Comment: You can do it by creating custom tags that do the same things as Spring tags. But you would only be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: When I remember right, reinventing the wheel, was the only solution I found for this problem one year ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `var` attribute of the `<security:authorize/>` tag which will create:

> A page scoped variable into which the boolean result of the tag
>   evaluation will be written, allowing the same condition to be reused
>   subsequently in the page without re-evaluation.

```xml
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" var="isUser" />
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" var="isAdmin" />
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_SADMIN')" var="isSuperUser" />

<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${isSuperUser}">
    You're a superadmin
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="${isAdmin}">
    You're an admin
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="${isUser}">
    You're an user
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    You have no relevant role
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

Workarround: When you have only this simple `hasRole(XXX)` expressions, then you could have a variable that contains the role of the current user. This variable could be populated by the controller, or when you needed it in almost all jsps, by an Spring [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) or Servlet Filter (that is registered after the Spring Security Filter).